# PHP script not able to read ajax post value in order to run the query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to post a variable clicked by an user to a PHP script in order to run a query which will further extract information from the database. I am able to get the value that has been clicked by an user without any issue. However I believe it is not getting processed within the query hence why when I run it in Firebug it shows an empty response and HTML.

I think I need some changes with my **test.php** script or may be ajax part of **index.php**

**Index.php**

```
<?php

$test  = $_GET['product'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$test' ";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$path_info = get_path();
$test1 = $path_info['call_parts'][1];

while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>
    <li class="nav" <?php if ($test1 == $list['slugs']) { echo'id="actives"'; } ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo $test;?>/<?php echo $list['slugs'];?> ">
            <?php echo $list['subgroup'] . "(" . $list['contains'] . ")" . '<br/>'; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" id="testing"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".nav > a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();   
            $.post("test.php", { value:$(this).text() }, function(data) {
                $("#testing").html(data);
            });
        });         
        //var classprod = $(this).text();
        //$("#testing").text(classprod);
    });
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require('../config/connection.php'); 
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE class = '$value'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $prdct = print_r ($row['product']);
        echo $prdct;
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: you have a `html form` with `method="post"`?

Comment: What are you expecting the value of `$_POST['value']` to be? Looks like it'll be `SubgroupName (Contains)`

Comment: You should check in Firebug what data are you sending in the request; also, you could echo the query you end up running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `"<br>"` from

```
<a href="<?php echo $test;?>/<?php echo $list['slugs'];?> ">

<?php echo $list['subgroup']."(".$list['contains'].")".'<br/>';?></a>
```

and try

or try in js as

```
  $.post("test.php", {value:(($(this).text()).trim())},
```

Comment: Thanks @safin chacko.  Could tell me a bit about this .trim()...it acted like a miracle for me :-)

Comment: trim() which removes spaces form both end of a string. Look here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$prdct = print_r ($row['product']);
```

To this:

```
 $prdct = $row['product'];
```

Also change this:

```
 $(".nav > a").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();   
 $.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, 
 function(data) {$("#testing").html(data);});
 });
```

To this:

```
$(".nav > a").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {value: $(this).text()},
    success: function( msg ){$("#testing").html(msg);}
    })
});
```

Comment: in firebug what headers are being sent?

Comment: Connection 
Keep-Alive
Content-Length 
2
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Tue, 16 Feb 2016 14:33:28 GMT
Keep-Alive 
timeout=5, max=97
Server 
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.6.14
view source
Accept 
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length 
32
Content-Type 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host 
localhost
Referer 
http://localhost:8080/series/dynamics/admin/cleanURL/postad
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
X-Requested-With 
XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ok then so the problem is from the request because no date has been sent through ajax request, i will edit my answer with an improve for the ajax request

Comment: What I used is a short hand of what you suggesting as Ajax. Unfortunately no deviation in final result.

Comment: check the headers now and see if the value is being sent

Comment: for a double check just print any value in test.php code, if you got a result then there is no problem just check your database and make sure that it matches what you are requesting

Comment: I wont get any output unless I hard code the $value as $_POST['value'] is relying on ajax script